# Is it possible to move a standard jQuery/AJAX/PHP workflow ALL server-side?

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery for validation and a multitude of plugins but i would like to move the jQuery validation especially to the server.
I usually backup client side validation with a set of PHP routines to catch any instances where JS may fail. Basically ...

Is it possible to use jQuery server-side? whilst researching this i can see potential solutions like, **Node.js, PhantomJS, JSDom, Cheerio** 
but i cannot see from the docs how i would use them with 3rd-party jQuery plugins, they seem geared to raw JS and running server instances.
Any advice to set me on the right path would be appreciated and i can explore further.

Comment: Never trust front-end validation... it has to be always on both sides

Comment: Typically we need to validate user input both on the client and server side.  Client side validation can always be hacked away, so we cannot rely on it alone to ensure safe data.

Comment: Ok, so after reading these answers there seems to be no conclusive answers to what i want - If for example i want to implement the popular  jquery.validate plugin to show dynamic error hints above/below a form input for example. Or implement a third-party plugin for adding a clock to the page etc ...